# Spring boot save data locally inside application

Tags: spring-boot

I have created a restful services using spring boot

In my controller class I have 2 methods
    `getEstimatePrice` ( I have only one product ) Which will calculate the price of productOrder with count of products and service tax and total (tax + product volume price)

```
Public double estimateProductPrice(int productID,int productCount)

Return productService.getProductEstimate
```

With `getEstimatePrice()` method I am creating an estimate object which have all the bill details (product price,tax,is)and will be displayed to the user

`purchaseProduct()` In this method I will have the same parameters as `getEstimatePrice()` along with coustmerId and it will create transaction object which I will save to database

What I am trying to do is I want to send the estimate object to purchase method .Because the objects that are created by `getEstimatePrice` and `purchaseProduct` is same but the `purchaseProduct()` method object has userId field is additional
So rather then creating that object for both method call I want to save the object when `getEstimatePrice()` method is called and when user picks confirm purchase method on the web page I want to send this estimateobject to `purchaseProduct` along with coustmerId
So I need to know how can I save the data among rest calls Temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use server side caching for this purpose, so you will cache the return value of `getEstimatePrice()` and when you call it after the first time, you will be getting the cached value instead of having to re-evaluate it.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial